# Python write to TempFile or to USB drive

Tags: python, linux, nas

Ultimately, I want to play movies from my Synology NAS on a Linux box connected to my TV. The Linux box is an Intel NUC running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has a 128 GB SSD and a 32 GB USB 3.0 drive (permanently attached), also there is 8 GB of memory. For reference the average movie file size is 5 GB.

I wrote a GUI in Python to handle the the movie title selection, NAS file retrieval and launching the movie in VLC player.

My question is in regards to temporary file storage location. The way I see it I have (2) obvious options: 1) I can use the `tempfile` module to store the movie until it is finished playing, or 2) I can write the movie to the USB drive.

My concern is I fear if i use the `tempfile` module I will slowly degrade my SSD until it fails. Assuming two movies will be watched on this machine per day means that 10 GB of data will be written to then erased from the SSD daily. If I use the USB drive I get the same wear and tear - the difference being the USB drive is way cheaper and easier to replace. Is this a credible concern or am I being overly cautious?

If it is possible I would prefer to save the movie to memory and play it from there, but I don't know how or if that is even possible. The issue being some of the movies are > 5 GB and the movie wouldn't fit in memory without some kind of circular buffer.

Any suggestions on which route is preferred?

Comment: Writing as a comment instead of an answer, because I can't say for sure if it will work or if it will hurt instead of help, but the tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile method may be an option here to make the best of both worlds

Comment: I read the docs and it appears if the file exceeds the `size` parameter then "the contents are written to disk". So some files get written to disk and others won't. This may help to reduce write operations, thanks.